# Accessing the raw data of hard disk using java

Tags: java, file-io, filesystems, disk

Is it possible to access the raw data (like traversing sector by sector) of hard disk using java ? If not, please tell the reason.....thnx in advance

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108313/how-to-access-specific-raw-data-on-disk-from-java