# Reading Disk in Java Gives Exception

Tags: java, disk, disk-partitioning

```
File diskRoot = new File ("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1");
    RandomAccessFile diskAccess = new RandomAccessFile (diskRoot, "r");
    byte[] content = new byte[512];
    diskAccess.readFully (content);
```

I am using the above mentioned code to read by PhysicalDrive1 and it gives me the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\.\HD1 (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at forensictool.ForensicTool.main(ForensicTool.java:43)
Java Result: 1
```

Is there any other method I can use to read from a physical drive in Java.

Comment: For raw data access (read/write) take a look at this SO-Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8610324/867816

Comment: Are you sure the error message matches your code? The file name is different...